# VSTO Excell Add-in InstallURL - where is it stored when I publish?

Tags: excel, vsto, clickonce

I have been digging into this for quite sometime to no avail. Thanks for any pointers.
Lets say you have a simple VSTO excel add-in. In the publish properties, I have specified a publish location and an installation location for end users. 
[image]

I click publish. Out comes a setup.exe, addin.vsto manifest and application files. I understand that I will eventually copy this to an install location specified in the properties.

**The question is - where exactly the "installation folder url" end up?**
I searched in the vsto manifest, resources in setup.exe and resources in the addin.dll etc.

Why I want to know is that at build time, I want to change the installation folder url. I tried passing a command line argument, but it seems that eventually when I publish a revision, the updates are not getting picked up on the end user machines. Now I am curious as to how this value that I enter in this dialog box is used by the publish process and where it ends up.

Thank you for reading and your time.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question since I spent more than a week on this and it might be useful to others.
At least for the scope of the question - You are developing an excel VSTO addin
The installation folder URL that you specify in the publish properties of Visual Studio is *not* used.  It might be used for document level customization, but not for application level add-ins.
Essentially when users install the add-in from an "installation folder url", the 
value of that is entered into the registry under Office\excel\addins, and this how the add-in checks for updates.

I wish the installtion folder url is grayed out for add-ins so it is clear that it is not really used. But now you know